# .net core 1 adding read only DB connection for 1 query

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a DB that is used by another web api.  I need to make one DB select query to this database in my application against one table and two fields.  I see I can create a database first DB context with some tools in .net core 1 by this [link](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html).  However it seems heavy handed to create this entire DBContext for a database that could change as the web api changes.  In addition I should not be writing to it.  So I can change the access in SQL server for the user to select only.  In addition I want to put my sql connection string in my appsettings.json file with all my other connection strings.

Question:  Is it possible to set up an sqlconnection in my controller similar to:

```
private readonly SqlConnection dbCon = new SQLConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBCon"));
```

Where my DBCon is defined in my appsettings.json file.  When I try to use the above I get the error:

> The name Configuration does not exist in the current context.

So apparently Configuration isn't the answer to getting the setting from appsettings.json.

I need to set up a quick sql connection for a simple query that doesn't take any user input without a lot of configuration.  Any help would be appreciated.

In 4.6 in console apps I could use ConfigurationManager to get the connectionstrings from app.config.  Not sure how to get it out of appsettings.json.  It may be getting it in Startup.cs but not sure how to get it in there and make it avaialable to the controller.

**Update:**
AppSettings.json is as follows:

```
{
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "valid Connection String",
    "DBCon": "valid Connection String"
  }, ....
```

Comment: Post the correct code. The one above isn't real code. You can't assign string to SqlConnection

Comment: @Tseng sorry I updated.  It was a sample of what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: And your appsettings.json?

Comment: @Tseng see update.

Comment: Were you calling this? The `Configuration` property is only accessible during startup in the `Startup.cs` class and there is no reason to access it outside, as both dependencies as well as options (`IOptions<T>`) can be now injected into other classes and services with ASP.NET Core

Comment: @Tseng that is what I am missing.  How to access these connection strings in the controllers.  I was trying to call Configuration in controller thinking that was what was accessable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and should) use dependency injection to achieve this.

I would create a simple service that has a method to execute your query.  The service class can have the connection string injected via an `IOptions` instance.  Alternatively, you can inject the options directly into the controller.

#### OtherDbOptions

```
public class OtherDbOptions
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

#### OtherDbService

```
public class OtherDbService
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public OtherDbService(IOptions<OtherDbOptions> options)
    {
        _connectionString = options.Value.ConnectionString;
    }

    public object GetData()
    {
        // create your database connection and return data
    }
}
```

#### Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // add options services
    services.AddOptions();

    // configure OtherDbOptions using code
    services.Configure<OtherDbOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ConnectionString = "value from appsettings.json";
    });

    // register OtherDbService for DI
    services.AddTransient<OtherDbService>();

    // other configurations
    ...
}
```

#### Controller (option 1 - inject service)

```
public OtherDbController(OtherDbService service)
{
    _service = service;
}
```

#### Controller (option 2 - inject options)

```
public OtherDbController(IOptions<OtherDbOptions> options)
{
    _options = options.Value;
}
```